# range tag adding incrementing/decrementing arrows to my editor field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I tried adding a range from 1-10 to a field in my model and it caused 2 mini arrows to appear to the right of my editor field that increment and decrement the value inside by 1. I would like to know how to remove these arrows. Any advice would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `@Html.Editor` html helper, use `@Html.TextBox`, this will solve your problem.

Because the property type is integer, if you'r using `@Html.Editor`, it will generate html like below:

```
<input type="number" id="Data" />
```

Notice the input element type is number, if your browser support `HTML 5`, it will show two arrows to the right. It's an html 5 feature.

But, if you're using `@Html.TextBox`, it will generate html like below:

```
<input type="text" id="Data" />
```

This time the type is text, it will not show the arrows.